# Nodejs/express redirect not going to redirect url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, http-redirect

Im using nodejs/express view engine in my application. This means that when the route points to an existent url, an assigned template would be rendered onto the screen. I have previously implemented a redirect to the homepage whenever a user types in an unexisting url. However, now, I have an wordpress endpoint which is `to/stores` and I am trying to do a redirect to that instead of a previous template that I had. The issue is that when I click on the href link, it goes straight to homepage, because this time it is not a template, but a route. So it doesnt fit into the 'view engine' type of view. Please see my code below for what I mean. Thanks!

Here in app.js, I am doing the redirecting to the homepage if there is an nonexisting route that:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = require('./routes/index');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const ENVIRONMENT = require('./common/config').ENVIRONMENT;
const BASE_URL = require('./common/config').BASE_URL;

const app = express();

app.locals.BASE_URL = BASE_URL;

app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
app.use('/', router);

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`listening in ${ENVIRONMENT} on port 3000!`));
```

And then in the index.js file, I declare my routes and the corresponding html files that will render. Keep in mind that the /stores route will be a redirect. It previously rendered a html file, but now I would like it to redirect to a wordpress endpoint `/to/stores` . But the result after clicking the href is going to the homepage.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const agentString = req.get('User-Agent');
  const referrer = req.get('Referrer');
  if ((referrer && referrer.includes('art.vpn.twttr.com/tweet_review')) || (agentString && agentString.includes('AdsBot'))) {
    res.render('bots/honeypot');
  } else {
    res.render('home', {title: defaultTitle, description: defaultDescription});
  }
});



router.get('/reddit', function (req, res) {
  res.render('bots/honeypot');
});

router.get('/facebook', function (req, res) {
  const clientIps = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
  if(!clientIps || userAgent.includes('facebookexternalhit')){
    res.render('bots/honeypot');
    return;
  }
  const ipMatchCidrs = areIp4sInCidrs(clientIps.split(','), BLACKLISTED_CIDRS);
  if (ipMatchCidrs) {
    res.render('bots/honeypot');
    return
  }

  const path = req.url.split('?');
  const queryString = path.length > 1 ? `?${path[1]}` : '';
  res.redirect(301, `/${queryString}`);
});

// THIS IS THE ROUTE THAT I AM TRYING TO DO THE 301 REDIRECT
router.get("/stores", (req, res) => {
  res.status(301).redirect("/to/stores")
})


router.get('/institutional', function (req, res) {
  res.render('institutional');
});

router.get('/institutional/checkout', function (req, res) {
  res.render('institutional-checkout');
});


router.get('/go/:page', function (req, res) {
  res.render('lps/' + req.params.page);
});

router.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.render('api');
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your application doesn't define "/to/stores" route, so user is first redirected to that route and then the catch all middleware redirects the user to homepage.

If you want to redirect user to different application, you need to use the absolute url of that application. i.e. res.status(301).redirect("https://example.com/to/stores")

If instead you want to handle "/to/stores" route in this application you need to add /to/stores route handler to your app, i.e.

```
router.get("/to/stores", (req, res) => {
  //TODO: Handle /to/stores route
});
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a noob, but is this the way to do do?
app.get("/stores", (req, res) => {
  res.status(301).redirect("https://www.example.com/to/stores")
})